# Grouping several targets into a single one

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Suppose I have a project with the following directory structure:

```
project
  src
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
  demos
    demo1.cpp
    demo2.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
  CMakeLists.txt
```

In the main `CMakeLists.txt` file, I have the following lines:

```
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(demos EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

As I understand, the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` parameter used for the `demos` directory has the effect of only building it explicitly. That is, to build both targets `demo1` and `demo2`, I need to execute:

```
make demo1
make demo2
```

My question is: is there a way to group all these `demo1` and `demo2` targets into a single `demos` target and then just type:

```
make demos
```

In a project with dozens of demos, building each one explicitly is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the solution! I will post here in case anybody else needs such behaviour.
The only thing that is necessary is to define a custom target as follow:

```
# Add target "demos" for building the demos
add_custom_target(demos
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/demos")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you can go to demos (cd demos) and type make there to make all demo-targets.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this. However, I think there is a way to type `make demos` without going to the `demos` directory. This project http://tinyurl.com/mahay35 does this. See `make demo`.